# Importing CSV to MonetDB

Tags: csv, monetdb

I am new for using `MonetDB`. I have imported `.csv` file in it.

However there are always the problem :

> sql>COPY INTO 123 FROM' C:\Program Files\MonetDB\112.csv' USING DELIMITERS '|', '|\n' LOCKED;
>   COPY INTO: filename must have absolute path:  C:\Program Files\MonetDB\112.csv

OR It display another question :

> sql>COPY INTO usgs FROM 'C:\Program Files\MonetDB\112.csv' USING DELIMITERS '|', '|\n' LOCKED;
>   Failed to import table '123', incomplete record at end of file

I do not konw how to solve it?

Comment: Who can help me? Urgency

Comment: Is you table named `123` or `usgs`? Do you get the same error if you change the second delimiter from `'|\n'` to `'\n'`?

Comment: I found that sometimes the `\ ` in windows is interpreted as an escape character by the monetdb parser. You might want to use a double `\\ ` for every `\ `

Answer (score 0):

Try `using delimiters '|', '\n', ''`. [Here](https://www.monetdb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6716#c5) discussion of this problem

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue a while ago when I was working on case-study. I have to resolve it via Pentaho ETL tool which ships with MonetDB BulkLoader.

I'm not sure that's how you want the stuff to run but for me it worked and it was fast as well.

Please refer to the article - https://medium.com/dataengineering-and-algorithms/the-use-of-column-store-database-for-data-warehousing-fcf8d3e1941c

Coming back to your question did you try changing the slash to '/' in the path.